# Merge schemas of custom dialog - Error conflicting definitions

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I am following the steps of this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions
and have reached to the part where it is required to merge the two schemas: bots and your custom one. However when running the powershell script found inside the created project template (CoreAssistant template) I have the following error:

> Error conflicting definitions of HelpDialog.dialog   :
> C:\Users\user\source\repos\AvanadeCoreAssistant\AvanadeCoreAssistant\dialogs\imported\Microsoft.Bot.Components.HelpAndCancel\HelpDialog\HelpDialog.dialog
> Microsoft.Bot.Components.HelpAndCancel:
> C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\microsoft.bot.components.helpandcancel\1.1.2\exported\HelpDialog\HelpDialog.dialog
> Error conflicting definitions of HelpDialog.en-us.lu.dialog   :
> C:\Users\user\source\repos\AvanadeCoreAssistant\AvanadeCoreAssistant\dialogs\imported\Microsoft.Bot.Components.HelpAndCancel\HelpDialog\recognizers\HelpDialog.en-us.lu.dialog
> Microsoft.Bot.Components.HelpAndCancel:
> C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\microsoft.bot.components.helpandcancel\1.1.2\exported\HelpDialog\recognizers\HelpDialog.en-us.lu.dialog
> Error conflicting definitions of HelpDialog.lu.dialog

HelpDialog is a predefined dialog that was already present. I have installed NodeJs and @botframework-cli package because it was required from the powershell script in order to run `bf dialog:merge` and now it seems these two sources have some kind of conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the script. I noticed the script was trying to ignore the folder imported and generated but the error message indicated it was not doing so. So I changed it from `!**/generated` to `!../generated`.

Comment: Hum... this tip didn't solve my error. Other than the conflicting error, I also got 'Error must have a merged .schema to merge .uischema files'...

Comment: That means that maybe the first merge didn't go well..you should see the custom action inside the main scheme if everything went well.

Comment: It seems a bug in the tool. See GitHub issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/8501

Answer (score 2):

To add to other answers, changes that worked for me are as follows:
update-schema.ps1, line 11, change "!**/generated" to "!../generated" and add "!../dialogs/imported"

Also, make sure that your custom action project is INSIDE of your bot directory, it should be a folder next to the "schemas" folder for the script to find it.

Note/Edit: Having the project nested inside the bot works to get the script working, though I do not recommend it due to causing other errors. Oddly, I found it was best to move the whole custom solution up a level, next to the bot project. You may have to edit the [botName].sln file in notepad to reference the location of the project, as well as editing the bot project's project reference.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue.
To fix this problem you could simply delete the corresponding dialogs in the "imported" folder. Note that this will, however, delete these dialogs in your bot, which is not optimal but should be of little concern for a sample application.